# Is there a way to download the contents of a folder from google cloud storage?

Tags: download, google-cloud-storage

I'm using google cloud storage to automate csv exports from big query. The way I have it set up currently creates a folder for each year > month > day > file.csv

So lets say I wanted to download an entire years worth of reports, can I just download that year folder and all the folders inside of it?

I'm not seeing a way to do this through the cloud storage dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it via the dashboard but you can via the [command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://my_bucket/2014 .
```

will download all contents of a folder to the current folder.